# How to return multiple values from a function in Kotlin like we do in Swift?

Tags: android, kotlin

How to return 3 separate data values of the same type (`Int`) from a function in Kotlin?

I'm attempting to return the time of day, I need to return the Hour, Minute and Second as separate integers, but all in one go from the same function, is this possible?

In swift we do it like following,

```
func getTime() -> (Int, Int, Int) {
    ...
    return ( hour, minute, second)
}
```

can we achieve this in Kotlin?

P.S: I know I can use Array or Hashmap for this but I want to know if there exists something in Kotlin like it is in Swift.

Comment: Check this: [This simple trick will have you creating multiple returns in Kotlin.](https://android.jlelse.eu/this-simple-trick-will-have-you-creating-multiple-returns-in-kotlin-37b9fe2a2f9f)

Answer (score 208, accepted):

You can't create arbitrary tuples in Kotlin, instead, you can use [data classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html). One option is using the built in [`Pair`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-pair/index.html) and [`Triple`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-triple/index.html) classes that are generic and can hold two or three values, respectively. You can use these combined with [destructuring declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html) like this:

```
fun getPair() = Pair(1, "foo")

val (num, str) = getPair()
```

You can also destructure a `List` or `Array`, for up to the first [5 elements](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/component5.html):

```
fun getList() = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

val (a, b, c, d, e) = getList()
```

The most idiomatic way however would be to define your own data class, which allows you to return a meaningful type from your function:

```
data class Time(val hour: Int, val minute: Int, val second: Int)

fun getTime(): Time {
    ...
    return Time(hour, minute, second)
}

val (hour, minute, second) = getTime()
```

Answer (score 31):

It seems that you are aware of the obvious answer of creating a specific class to handle time. So I guess you are trying to avoid the small hassle of creating a class, or accessing each element of an array, etc. and are looking for the shortest solution in terms of extra code. I would suggest:

```
fun getTime(): Triple<Int, Int, Int> {
    ...
    return Triple( hour, minute, second)
}
```

and use it with deconstruction:

```
var (a, b, c) = getTime()
```

If you need 4 or 5 return values (you cannot deconstruct more than 5), go with `Array`:

```
fun getTime(): Array<Int> {
    ...
    return arrayOf( hour, minute, second, milisec)
}
```

and

```
var (a, b, c, d) = getTime()
```

P.S.: you can use less variables than there are values when deconstructing, like `var (a, b) = getTime()` but you cannot use more or you'll get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 25):

While, generally, a function can return only a single value, in Kotlin, by leveraging the benefits of the Pair type and destructuring declarations, we can return two variables from a function. Consider the following example:

```
fun getUser():Pair<Int,String> {//(1) 
  return Pair(1,"Mahabub") 
} 

fun main(args: Array<String>) { 
  val (userID,userName) = getUser()//(2) 
  println("User ID: $userID t User Name: $userName") 
}
```

From: Functional Kotlin book

Comment: Brilliant Solution.

Answer (score 6):

According to the Kotlin documentation (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html#example-returning-two-values-from-a-function) you can achieve it like that:

```
data class TimeData(val hour: Int, val minute: Int, val second: Int)

fun getTime(): TimeData {
    // do your calculations

    return TimeData(hour, minute, second)
}

// Get the time.
val (hour, minute, second) = getTime()
```

Answer (score 5):

> Use Triple to return 3 values and Pair to return 2 values

```
class Book(val title: String, val author: String, val year: Int) {


fun getTitleAuthor(): Pair<String, String> {
    return (title to author)
}

fun getTitleAuthorYear(): Triple<String, String, Int> {
    return Triple(title, author, year)
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are under special constraints and are looking to return multiple value without any class allocations, you may want to do something like [this](https://blog.louiscad.com/how-to-return-2-values-with-0-allocation-in-kotlin)

```kotlin
val theBonus: Bonus
val theStuff = getStuff { theBonus = it }

doSomething(theStuff, theBonus)
```

where

```kotlin
import kotlin.contracts.*

@OptIn(ExperimentalContracts::class)
inline fun getStuff(block: (Bonus) -> Unit): Stuff {
    contract { callsInPlace(block, InvocationKind.EXACTLY_ONCE) }
    val stuff = grabStuffFromCargoBikeBasket()
    val bonus = inspirationElixir()
    block(bonus)
    return stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no tuple in Kotlin. Alternatively, you can use [data class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html#data-classes) with [destructuring declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html#destructuring-declarations).

```
data class Time(val hour: Int, val minute: Int, val second: Int)

func getTime(): Time {
    ...
    return Time(hour, minute, second)
}

//Usage
val time = getTime()
println("${time.hour}:${time.minute}:${time.second}")
//Or
val (hour, minute, second) = getTime()
println("${hour}:${minute}:${second}")
```

If you don't want to create data class for each specific case, you may create some generic data classes and use `typealias` for clarity.

```
data class Two<A, B>(val a: A, val b: B)
data class Three<A, B, C>(val a: A, val b: B, val c: C)
data class Four<A, B, C, D>(val a: A, val b: B, val c: C, val d: D)
...

typealias Time = Three<Int, Int, Int>
```

But, obviously, the disadvantage is that you must make use of destructuring declaration in order to give it a proper property name.

```
val time = getTime()
println("${time.a}:${time.b}:${time.c}")

val (hour, minute, second) = getTime()    //destructuring declaration
println("${hour}:${minute}:${second}")
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to return multiple values of different types without using a class with destructuring declarations, you can also use a `List` of type `Any` for that purpose:

```
fun main() {
    val (a, b, c) = getData()
    println(a)
    println(b)
    println(c)
}

fun getData(): List<Any> {
    val one = Int.MAX_VALUE
    val two: List<Long> = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
    val three: Pair<String, Char> = "a" to 'z'
    return listOf(one, two, three)
}
```

This is the output:

```
2147483647
[1, 2, 3, 4]
(a, z)
```

Comment: It would require to explicit conversion of returned values as because return type has been define as ```List<Any>```. Thank you anyway, it is a good technique.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is about returning functions but a lambda could do the work as well
(LocalDateTime might not work in the older versions)

```
private fun getReadableTime(onTime: (hour: Int, min: Int, sec: Int)->Unit) {
val time = LocalDateTime.now()
val hour = time.hour
val min = time.minute
val sec = time.second

onTime(hour, min, sec)
}
```

Usage :

```
getReadableTime { hour, min, sec ->
                    println("$hour : $min : $sec")
                }
```