# How can I return more than one value in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to return the 4 vals (notDev, lastIndex, lastIndexValue, firstIndexValue)

I have tried return expression and changed the fun outputs to

```
fun whenNotZero(): (Int, Int, Int, Int) -> Unit{//rest of the code
return{notDiv, lastIndex, lastIndexValue, firstIndexValue}
}
```

then I tried doing this

```
fun whenNotZero(order:Int): Int {//rest of the code
   if(order == 1){return notDiv}
   if(order == 2){return lastIndex}
   if(order == 3){return lastIndexValue}
   if(order == 4){return firstIndexValue}
}
```

Is there's any way I can return these values like python or returning them at all ?

python code

```py
def foo():
    # code here
    return(notDiv, lastIndex, lastIndexValue, firstIndexValue)
values = foo()
print(values[0])
```

my current kotlin code

```
fun whenNotZero() {
   val seq = mutableListOf<Int>()
   val inDevSeq = mutableListOf<Int>()
   for (i in range1..range2) {
       if (i % divisible_number == 0){inDevSeq.add(i);seq.add(i)}else{seq.add(i)}
   }

   val notDiv = seq.sum() - inDevSeq.sum()
   val lastIndex = inDevSeq.count()
   val lastIndexValue = inDevSeq.last()
   val firstIndexValue = inDevSeq.first()
}
```

Comment: answer already available i think follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47308092/10182897

Comment: you can return only 1 value in Java and Kotlin. If you need to return more - create a class having all them as fields, and return the object of that class

Comment: even if you can only return one value you can unpack the value on callsite into multiple values again, dataclasses make this easy for you